# why opencv imshow() create a new window has the same name as namedWindow() does in Debug Mode?

Tags: opencv

I want to create a mat and show it in a window named "figure".

If there is nothing wrong, there should be a window named "figure", and accept any key to stop.

In Release mode, the following code works finely.
but in Debug mode, the `imshow()` will create a new window which has the same name with the window create by `nameWindow()`. and only the figure created by `namedWindow()` accepts my input.

```
#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>

const std::string winName = "figure";
int main() {
    cv::Mat m;
    cv::namedWindow(winName,cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    m.create(300, 300, CV_32FC3);
    m.setTo(cv::Scalar(0.0f, 2.0f, 5.0f));

    cv::imshow(winName, m);
    cv::waitKey(0);

}
```

[image]

Comment: @Miki the window will disappear right away and program will stop immediately, if don't use `namedWindow()`. the code still did not work according your suggesting.

Comment: That's even more wierd. You don't need namedWindow here. I suspect some issues with the project setup. Can you show the libraries you link in debug mode?

Comment: @Miki Library: `D:\ProgramFiles\opencv3.3.1\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib;$(LibraryPath)`Directory: `D:\ProgramFiles\opencv3.3.1\opencv\build\include\opencv2;D:\ProgramFiles\opencv3.3.1\opencv\build\include\opencv;D:\ProgramFiles\opencv3.3.1\opencv\build\include;$(IncludePath)` Additional Dependencies `opencv_world331.lib;opencv_world331d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Comment: Ok, that's probably the problem. In release you should link **only** to `opencv_world331.lib`, and in debug **only** to `opencv_world331d.lib`. Also I assume you're using visual studio 2015, and your project is 64 bit, right?

Comment: @Miki Additional Dependencies `opencv_world331.lib;opencv_world331d.lib;%(AdditionalDepende‌​ncies)`

Comment: @Miki Sure! That's it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is due to wrong linking settings.

- In **Debug**, you need to link only to the debug library `opencv_world331d.lib`
- In **Release**, you need to link only to the release library `opencv_world331.lib`

Comment: Thanks.  I ran into the same problem, because my prop sheet was linking both debug and release libs.  This was working fine with opencv341, but broke with opencv341_build.  Splitting my `<ItemDefinitionGroup>` tag into  `<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">` and `<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">`, so as to only link one opencv lib at a time, fixed the issue.