# Mouse Handling create second window (OPEN CV / C++ / Win 10)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

i'm new guy in Open CV. My problem is about second window when using setMouseCallback. Below is my code.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Point center, circumference;

// Source image
Mat image;
Mat source;

void drawCircle(int action, int x, int y, int flags, void *userdata)
{
    // Action to be taken when left mouse button is pressed
    if (action == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        center = Point(x, y);
        cout << "DOWN";
        // Mark the center
        circle(source, center, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2, CV_AA);
    }
    // Action to be taken when left mouse button is released
    else if (action == EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        circumference = Point(x, y);
        // Calculate radius of the circle
        float radius = sqrt(pow(center.x - circumference.x, 2) +
            pow(center.y - circumference.y, 2));
        // Draw the circle
        circle(source, center, radius, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, CV_AA);
        imshow("Window", source);
    }
}
```

And main function.

```
int main()
{
    image = imread("sample.jpg", 1);
    cv::resize(image, source, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, INTER_LINEAR);
    // Make a dummy image, will be useful to clear the drawing
    Mat dummy = source.clone();
    namedWindow("Window",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    // highgui function called when mouse events occur
    setMouseCallback("Window", drawCircle);
    int k = 0;
    // loop until escape character is pressed
    while (k != 27)
    {
        imshow("Window", source);
        putText(source, "Choose center, and drag, Press ESC to exit and c to clear", Point(10, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        k = waitKey(20) & 0xFF;
        if (k == 99)
            // Another way of cloning
        dummy.copyTo(source);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i run it, it make two window with same name, first one is show my image, second one is a gray window, all of them are same size, window with image is above the gray window. And my handle only work in gray window, and when i draw on it, it draw on window image, Gray window look like a handle layer of my program. How to merger it to one window.
Thanks.!

Comment: Totally unrelated: `pow` is designed to handle operations like e to the power of pi and can be quite slow as a result. Using it to square numbers is usually much slower than `x*x`

Comment: Can you please make your post a bit more undersrandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
[why opencv imshow() create a new window has the same name as namedWindow() does in Debug Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608620/why-opencv-imshow-create-a-new-window-has-the-same-name-as-namedwindow-does)